# How to map this using AutoMapper 11.0.0?

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a model classes shown below.

```
    public class ModelA
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string DetailId{ get; set; }
        public string DetailName { get; set; }
        public string DetailDescription { get; set; }
    }

    public class ModelB
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

    public class ModelC
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public ModelB Detail { get; set; }
    }
```

Now, I want to map ModelA to ModelC where

- DetailId = Detail.Id
- DetailName = Detail.Name
- DetailDescription = Detail.Description

Is this possible using Automapper 11.0.0 ?
If possible, how ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers.

However I solved it already.

```
    MapperConfiguration _config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {

        cfg.CreateMap<ModelA, ModelB>()
            .ForMember(d => d.DetailId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Id))
            .ForMember(d => d.DetailName , opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Name))
            .ForMember(d => d.DetailDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Description))
            .ReverseMap();


        cfg.CreateMap<ModelC, ModelA>()
            .ForMember(d => d.DetailId, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Detail.Id ))
            .ForMember(d => d.DetailName , opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Detail.Name ))
            .ForMember(d => d.DetailDescription, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Detail.Description ))

        cfg.CreateMap<ModelA, ModelC>()
            .ForMember(d => d.Detail, opt => opt.MapFrom(s => Mapper.Map<ModelA, ModelB>(s)))

    });
```

**UPDATE**

Found a better solution.
Check out the link below.

https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/mapping-complex-type-to-primitive-type-using-automapper/

Comment: Prefer accept answer than post your own that use the code from other answer

Comment: Great check your question as answered please

Comment: Check as answered

Comment: I can't, it says "You can accept your own answer in 2 days"

Answer (score 1):

```
    var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
    cfg.CreateMap< ModelA, ModelC >().ForMember(u => u. Detail, o => o.MapFrom(s => s));
});
```

You want the modelB mapping in modelC,But the structure of modelA is different from that of modelC.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
CreateMap<ModelA, ModelC>()
    .ForMember(d => d.Detail.Id, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.DetailId))
    .ForMember(d => d.Detail.Description, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.DetailDescription))
    .ForMember(d => d.Detail.Name, src => src.MapFrom(e => e.DetailName))
    .ReverseMap();
```

Comment: https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

Comment: Thanks @LucianBargaoanu, I had not seen the documentation of the new version